# 'rake assets: precompile' giving me errors in development and production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, precompile

Whenever I try to deploy my app with `cap production deploy:migrations` I get an error message along the lines:

```
 * executing "ln -nfs /var/www/apps/myapp/releases/20130802221024/config/configs/resque_schedule.yml /var/www/apps/myapp/releases/20130802221024/config/resque_schedule.yml"
    servers: ["12.34.567.8"]
    [12.34.567.8] executing command
    command finished in 550ms
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:update_code'
  * executing `deploy:assets:precompile'
  * executing "cd /var/www/apps/myapp/releases/20130802221024 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile"
    servers: ["12.34.567.8"]
    [12.34.567.8] executing command
 ** [out :: 12.34.567.8] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: 12.34.567.8] Received wrong number of arguments. [nil]
 ** [out :: 12.34.567.8] /var/www/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/omniauth-1.1.0/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:136:in `initialize'
 ** [out :: 12.34.567.8] /var/www/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:43:in `new'
 ** [out :: 12.34.567.8] /var/www/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:43:in `build'
```

I had been believed there was some configuration issue with my server, or some missing dependency files. But on my local Ubuntu when I run in terminal:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
```

I get:

```
    mycompaq@ubuntu:~/myapp$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
DEPRECATION WARNING: require "activerecord" is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 3. Use require "active_record" instead. (called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/activerecord.rb:2)
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/usr/bin/ruby1.8 /usr/local/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
DEPRECATION WARNING: require "activerecord" is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 3. Use require "active_record" instead. (called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/activerecord.rb:2)
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
Received wrong number of arguments. [nil]
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/omniauth-1.1.0/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:136:in `initialize'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:43:in `new'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:43:in `build'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:113:in `build'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:282:in `inject'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:113:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:113:in `inject'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:113:in `build'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:470:in `build_middleware_stack'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:31
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `run_initializers'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/home/mycompaq/myapp/config/environment.rb:5
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:292:in `initialize_tasks'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:93
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:183:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/bin/rake:33
/usr/local/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:19
Tasks: TOP => environment
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/usr/bin/ruby1.8 /usr/local/bin/rake asset...]
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `create_shell_runner'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `sh'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:80:in `ruby'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `ruby'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:12:in `ruby_rake_task'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:21:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/bin/rake:33
/usr/local/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:19
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

Here's my devise.rb:

```
# Use this hook to configure devise mailer, warden hooks and so forth.
# Many of these configuration options can be set straight in your model.
Devise.setup do |config|
  # ==> Mailer Configuration
  # Configure the e-mail address which will be shown in Devise::Mailer,
  # note that it will be overwritten if you use your own mailer class with default "from" parameter.
  config.mailer_sender = "no-reply@myapp.com"

  # Configure the class responsible to send e-mails.
  # config.mailer = "Devise::Mailer"

  # Automatically apply schema changes in tableless databases
  config.apply_schema = false

  # ==> ORM configuration
  # Load and configure the ORM. Supports :active_record (default) and
  # :mongoid (bson_ext recommended) by default. Other ORMs may be
  # available as additional gems.
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'

  # ==> Configuration for any authentication mechanism
  # Configure which keys are used when authenticating a user. The default is
  # just :email. You can configure it to use [:username, :subdomain], so for
  # authenticating a user, both parameters are required. Remember that those
  # parameters are used only when authenticating and not when retrieving from
  # session. If you need permissions, you should implement that in a before filter.
  # You can also supply a hash where the value is a boolean determining whether
  # or not authentication should be aborted when the value is not present.
  # config.authentication_keys = [ :email ]

  # Configure parameters from the request object used for authentication. Each entry
  # given should be a request method and it will automatically be passed to the
  # find_for_authentication method and considered in your model lookup. For instance,
  # if you set :request_keys to [:subdomain], :subdomain will be used on authentication.
  # The same considerations mentioned for authentication_keys also apply to request_keys.
  # config.request_keys = []

  # Configure which authentication keys should be case-insensitive.
  # These keys will be downcased upon creating or modifying a user and when used
  # to authenticate or find a user. Default is :email.
  config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email ]

  # Configure which authentication keys should have whitespace stripped.
  # These keys will have whitespace before and after removed upon creating or
  # modifying a user and when used to authenticate or find a user. Default is :email.
  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :email ]

  # Tell if authentication through request.params is enabled. True by default.
  # It can be set to an array that will enable params authentication only for the
  # given strategies, for example, `config.params_authenticatable = [:database]` will
  # enable it only for database (email + password) authentication.
  # config.params_authenticatable = true

  # Tell if authentication through HTTP Basic Auth is enabled. False by default.
  # It can be set to an array that will enable http authentication only for the
  # given strategies, for example, `config.http_authenticatable = [:token]` will
  # enable it only for token authentication.
  # config.http_authenticatable = false

  # If http headers should be returned for AJAX requests. True by default.
  # config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = true

  # The realm used in Http Basic Authentication. "Application" by default.
  # config.http_authentication_realm = "Application"

  # It will change confirmation, password recovery and other workflows
  # to behave the same regardless if the e-mail provided was right or wrong.
  # Does not affect registerable.
  # config.paranoid = true

  # By default Devise will store the user in session. You can skip storage for
  # :http_auth and :token_auth by adding those symbols to the array below.
  # Notice that if you are skipping storage for all authentication paths, you
  # may want to disable generating routes to Devise's sessions controller by
  # passing :skip => :sessions to `devise_for` in your config/routes.rb
  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]

  # ==> Configuration for :database_authenticatable
  # For bcrypt, this is the cost for hashing the password and defaults to 10. If
  # using other encryptors, it sets how many times you want the password re-encrypted.
  #
  # Limiting the stretches to just one in testing will increase the performance of
  # your test suite dramatically. However, it is STRONGLY RECOMMENDED to not use
  # a value less than 10 in other environments.
  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10

  # Setup a pepper to generate the encrypted password.
  # config.pepper = "9297a3b06e77e9730672dccc5cf9d9da555707c9b711d36115f4109352aee73e399163a22d8c59493ef09096d7b94b63ddfc4c16af432b46cab64f22b1a0be23"

  # ==> Configuration for :confirmable
  # A period that the user is allowed to access the website even without
  # confirming his account. For instance, if set to 2.days, the user will be
  # able to access the website for two days without confirming his account,
  # access will be blocked just in the third day. Default is 0.days, meaning
  # the user cannot access the website without confirming his account.
  # config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 2.days

  # If true, requires any email changes to be confirmed (exctly the same way as
  # initial account confirmation) to be applied. Requires additional unconfirmed_email
  # db field (see migrations). Until confirmed new email is stored in
  # unconfirmed email column, and copied to email column on successful confirmation.
  config.reconfirmable = true

  # Defines which key will be used when confirming an account
  # config.confirmation_keys = [ :email ]

  # ==> Configuration for :rememberable
  # The time the user will be remembered without asking for credentials again.
  config.remember_for = 2.weeks

  # If true, extends the user's remember period when remembered via cookie.
  config.extend_remember_period = true

  # If true, uses the password salt as remember token. This should be turned
  # to false if you are not using database authenticatable.
  config.use_salt_as_remember_token = true

  # Options to be passed to the created cookie. For instance, you can set
  # :secure => true in order to force SSL only cookies.
  # config.cookie_options = {}

  # ==> Configuration for :validatable
  # Range for password length. Default is 6..128.
  # config.password_length = 6..128

  # Email regex used to validate email formats. It simply asserts that
  # an one (and only one) @ exists in the given string. This is mainly
  # to give user feedback and not to assert the e-mail validity.
  # config.email_regexp = /\A[^@]+@[^@]+\z/

  # ==> Configuration for :timeoutable
  # The time you want to timeout the user session without activity. After this
  # time the user will be asked for credentials again. Default is 30 minutes.
  # config.timeout_in = 30.minutes

  # ==> Configuration for :lockable
  # Defines which strategy will be used to lock an account.
  # :failed_attempts = Locks an account after a number of failed attempts to sign in.
  # :none            = No lock strategy. You should handle locking by yourself.
  # config.lock_strategy = :failed_attempts

  # Defines which key will be used when locking and unlocking an account
  # config.unlock_keys = [ :email ]

  # Defines which strategy will be used to unlock an account.
  # :email = Sends an unlock link to the user email
  # :time  = Re-enables login after a certain amount of time (see :unlock_in below)
  # :both  = Enables both strategies
  # :none  = No unlock strategy. You should handle unlocking by yourself.
  # config.unlock_strategy = :both

  # Number of authentication tries before locking an account if lock_strategy
  # is failed attempts.
  # config.maximum_attempts = 20

  # Time interval to unlock the account if :time is enabled as unlock_strategy.
  # config.unlock_in = 1.hour

  # ==> Configuration for :recoverable
  #
  # Defines which key will be used when recovering the password for an account
  # config.reset_password_keys = [ :email ]

  # Time interval you can reset your password with a reset password key.
  # Don't put a too small interval or your users won't have the time to
  # change their passwords.
  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours

  # ==> Configuration for :encryptable
  # Allow you to use another encryption algorithm besides bcrypt (default). You can use
  # :sha1, :sha512 or encryptors from others authentication tools as :clearance_sha1,
  # :authlogic_sha512 (then you should set stretches above to 20 for default behavior)
  # and :restful_authentication_sha1 (then you should set stretches to 10, and copy
  # REST_AUTH_SITE_KEY to pepper)
  # config.encryptor = :sha512

  # ==> Configuration for :token_authenticatable
  # Defines name of the authentication token params key
  # config.token_authentication_key = :auth_token

  # ==> Scopes configuration
  # Turn scoped views on. Before rendering "sessions/new", it will first check for
  # "users/sessions/new". It's turned off by default because it's slower if you
  # are using only default views.
  config.scoped_views = true

  # Configure the default scope given to Warden. By default it's the first
  # devise role declared in your routes (usually :user).
  # config.default_scope = :user

  # Configure sign_out behavior.
  # Sign_out action can be scoped (i.e. /users/sign_out affects only :user scope).
  # The default is true, which means any logout action will sign out all active scopes.
  config.sign_out_all_scopes = false

  # ==> Navigation configuration
  # Lists the formats that should be treated as navigational. Formats like
  # :html, should redirect to the sign in page when the user does not have
  # access, but formats like :xml or :json, should return 401.
  #
  # If you have any extra navigational formats, like :iphone or :mobile, you
  # should add them to the navigational formats lists.
  #
  # The "*/*" below is required to match Internet Explorer requests.
  # config.navigational_formats = ["*/*", :html]

  # The default HTTP method used to sign out a resource. Default is :delete.
  config.sign_out_via = :delete

  # ==> OmniAuth
  # Add a new OmniAuth provider. Check the wiki for more information on setting
  # up on your models and hooks.
  # config.omniauth :github, 'APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET', :scope => 'user,public_repo'
  OAUTH_CONFIG_PATH = Rails.root.join("config", "oauth.yml")
  if File.exists?(OAUTH_CONFIG_PATH)
    OAUTH_CONFIG = YAML.load_file(OAUTH_CONFIG_PATH)[Rails.env]
    config.omniauth :facebook, OAUTH_CONFIG['facebook']['app_id'], OAUTH_CONFIG['facebook']['app_secret'], OAUTH_CONFIG['facebook']['options']
  else
    Rails.logger.warn("Could not find oauth.yml in config directory.")
  end


  # ==> Warden configuration
  # If you want to use other strategies, that are not supported by Devise, or
  # change the failure app, you can configure them inside the config.warden block.
  #
  # config.warden do |manager|
  #   manager.intercept_401 = false
  #   manager.default_strategies(:scope => :user).unshift :some_external_strategy
  # end
end
```

Here's my oauth.yml

```
development:
  facebook:
    app_id: "144574445xxxxxx"
    app_secret: "501bf4e3202cd8578e3223xxxxxxxxxx"
    options:
      scope: "email"
      display: "page"

staging: &staging
  facebook:
    app_id: "144574445xxxxxx"
    app_secret: "501bf4e3202cd8578e3223xxxxxxxxxx"
    options:
      scope: "email"
      display: "page"

test:
  <<: *staging

production:
  facebook:
    app_id: "144574445xxxxxx"
    app_secret: "501bf4e3202cd8578e3223xxxxxxxxxx"
```

Comment: It's pretty straightforward, Omniauth "Received wrong number of arguments. [nil]", if you did read the log you'd find the file causing this (it's in your project not in gems)

Comment: Log from `$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace`

Comment: But where is that log file? Are you talking about the whole list of lines that appears in Ubuntu Terminal after I run the command? Because I don't think that yields anything constructive - just lists a load of  gem files and issues like, '/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `top_level' etc...

Comment: I didn't mention any log file and I guess if you'd see anything in the log you wouldn't post your question here, would you? So please post full result of mentioned command.

Comment: I added my log when I run the command to my question.

Comment: So line 5 of environment.rb is mentioned, but I guess it will be something like `MyApp::Application.initialize!` which suggests (as well as that it is Omniauth problem) that you have an error in your initializer. Please paste contents of either `devise.rb` or `omniauth.rb`

Comment: Also I bet that neither `rails c` nor `rails s` works for you with the same error.

Comment: In fact, rails c and rails s work perfectly. And you're right - MyApp::Application.initialize! is line 5. I don't have an omniauth.rb in my config/initializers folder. Is that normal? I have an oauth.yml in config. I've pasted my devise.rb, above.

Comment: Is this `OAUTH_CONFIG['facebook']['options']` a hash for sure? I don't see any other options left.

Comment: How can I find out if it's a 'hash'? Sorry, but someone else started this project from scratch and I took over, so my rails isn't the best. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You may paste `oauth.yml` just remove app_id and app_secret!

Comment: pasted my oauth.yml. I have the same keys in all the environments, but surely that makes no difference?

Comment: Ok, I looked into Omniauth code and it doesn't make any sense to me. It looks like somehow nil is passed in args to strategy initializer. What I would do it use pry and try to see what gets passed to the gem here https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/blob/v1.1.0/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb#L124 (yes, it requires you to edit gem files on your local machine)

Comment: Other possibility is to try updating Omniauth to latest version which is 1.1.4 (vs. 1.1.0 which you use)

Comment: Thanks for all that.out of the office at the moment but I'll take a closer look when I'm back.